# {SAS} Converting a SQL merge in to HASH merge

Tags: sql, merge, sas, hashtable

```
proc sql;
create table ndd1 as
 select a.*, 1 as default_flag, b.retail_account_no, c.limit
 from (
     select 
         posting_date, counterparty_id, counterparty_indicator, customer_id, last_default_date, last_out_of_default_date
     from gdwh30.tb0_default
     where counterparty_id<>'*noval*' 
     and ((last_out_of_default_date < posting_date and last_default_date >= last_out_of_default_date)
     or (last_out_of_default_date > posting_date and last_default_date < last_out_of_default_date))
     and posting_date = to_date(%nrbquote(')&tt.%nrbquote('), 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi')) a
 left join (
     select retail_account_no, REF_account_ID, regexp_substr(REF_account_ID,'[^*]+', 1) as counterparty_id
     from gdwh30.TB0_account
/*tb_account*/
     where bus_date_from<= to_date(%nrbquote(')&tt.%nrbquote('), 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi')
     and bus_date_until>=to_date(%nrbquote(')&tt.%nrbquote('), 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:mi')
     and entity_id='RBBG') b
 on a.counterparty_id=b.counterparty_id
;quit;
```

&tt. is of the form

30APR2020:00:00:00

or date22.

```
data ndd_1; 
if 0 then set gdwh30.tb0_default today ;
if _n_=1 then do;
    declare hash k(dataset:"gdwh30.tb0_default");
    k.definekey ("posting_date");
        k.definedata ("counterparty_id", "posting_date", "last_out_of_default_date", "last_default_date");
        k.definedone();

        declare hash j(dataset:"today");
        j.definekey("today1");
        j.definedata ("today1");
        j.definedone();
    
end;
set ndd_1;
if k.find(key:posting_date)=0 and j.find(key:today1)=0 then output;
run;
```

What I  think is must do is format the columns pre *N*=1;

For the second join on Tb0_acc I want to attempt a fuzzy merger so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Today1 is &tt. but in a table instead of a list. I first try to join the A part just to get a feel for these hash joins.

Posting_date is of the form 31AUG2016:00:00:00

Comment: I don't see a question here.  What do you need help with?  What's the error you're dealing with?  And "fuzzy merger" I don't know what you mean there, exactly, but if you're trying to use a hash table to do an approximate match, you're going to have some issues - hash requires identical match on the match key, so it doesn't really help there, and *we* can't really help without a lot more details (and it sounds like this is two or more questions?).

Comment: @Joe, Well it seems that when comparing posting_date keys and Today key they don't identify as a match. So how do I format the tables before creating the keys is my question.

Comment: https://sasnrd.com/fuzzy-hash-object-merge-sas/ 

On fuzzy mergers with hash objects.

Comment: Can you clean up the question, and put that key information (not identify as a match) in the question?  And remove the fuzzy match stuff, that can be another question if needed.  (And - while it's certainly possible to use do_over() - it's horribly inefficient... any hash solution that requires going through the entire hash for every row is not going to be performant, unless there are relatively few possible fuzzy matches.)